# How to add the new line without space after ',' in print() in Python

Tags: python, printing, newline

There is two data and printing the length of them.
**Code:**

```
print(len(author),'\n',len(authorUnique))
```

**and output**:

```
5439 
 4443
```

*I would like to get*:

```
5439 
4443
```

What can I do to get what I want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print without a newline or space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-a-newline-or-space)

Comment: Sorry, to me it looks like your expected and desired outputs are the same, could you elaborate?

Comment: The difference between them is a space at the beginning of second line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't print them at once! It's much simpler to split this up into two separate `print` statements, which also solves your problem:

```py
print(len(author))
print(len(authorUnique))
```

If you *do* only want to use one print statement, however, you need to specify the right separator token, like this:

```py
print(len(author), len(authorUnique), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions. 
And I wanted to know more about print(), so I wanted to do in one print statement.
It works!